# Executing a Test Class extending AndroidTestCase in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to execute a test class extending an AndroidTestCase that I've made but apparently I've kept on getting the following error:

```
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop package_name 
Running tests 
Test running started
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for:
ComponentInfo{package_name/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.
```

The only solution that I remember that I found is that I need to indicate my InstrumentationTestRunner in the Run/Debug Configurations. But even though I've specified the instrumentation runner of Android API 21, I still get the error mentioned above. Other solutions points out on adding some info in `build.gradle` but it isn't possible since my Android Project is generated by IBM MobileFirst and Gradle is not supported.

For my code, please check below:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

import <package>.R;
import <package>.<Class to be tested>;

public class SampleTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    @SmallTest
    public void testHidePartsOfLicense(){
        <Class to be tested> sample = new <Class to be tested>();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(super.getContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.testImage);

        String imageString = sample.addShapesInBitmapImage(bitmap);

        assertNotNull(imageString);
    }
}
```

Or are there other ways to me to be able to just execute a simple JUnit Test with the bitmap image? As much as I'd like to use the `java.awt.image` package, I read that it is not possible in Android Studio as well..

---

[EDIT]

So I tried adding the following code in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="package_name"/>`
`<uses-library android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestCase"/>`

But apparently, there's something wrong with my `package_name` and `Cannot resolve symbol 'package_name'` is shown.

If I try to execute the test, the following error is shown:
`Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'`

Comment: While MobileFirst does not support Gradle, I am not sure why is this an issue for you. Your code snippet does not contain any code that relates to MobileFirst to begin with.

Comment: Hello @IdanAdar, I just want to post in advance to whomever reads this that I am won't able to fix my issue if their answer is to place some lines of codes in the `build.gradle` or any Gradle related fix. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix my issue yesterday...

Basically it's alright that the package_name to get red in Android Studio. The important thing is instead of placing `<uses-library android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestCase"/>` under the `<application>` tag, place `<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>`